# HTTP Header response code

Tags: http, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes

I installed a plugin on my Wordpress website to redirect all missing pages to the homepage. The plugin seems to be working ok but the header response code for the redirected page is 202. Shouldn't it be 301?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

#### 10.2.3 202 Accepted

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
> not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted
> upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
> There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous
> operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to
> allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
> batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
> requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until
> the process is completed. The entity returned with this response
> SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and
> either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user
> can expect the request to be fulfilled.

The core of the message is in the first sentence:

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed

and indeed you're right - this is *not* the correct response code to your scenario! 301 would be a better fit and you are welcome to submit a bug to the writers of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean but then I'm no expert. I deactivated the plugin and get a 404. After reactivating it I get the 202 response code. So, it seems to be doing what it's supposed to but I thought it strange that it wasn't showing a 301 response code.

Comment: What I mean is: 202 is not the correct response code in that scenario. 301 will fit better.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Actually, the documentation for the plugin does say the missing pages are handled using a 301 redirect.

Comment: Then there are two options: 1) you're not checking the redirect properly. 2) they're wrong